Dynamic IP causing frequent connection dropouts on my devices, any solution in router settings?
So I recently had my router replaced by my ISP since the old one stopped working, but when it was working it worked great, specifically with my range extender. The new router on the other hand has brought issues, namely that when my devices are connected to the extender's network, the connection will frequently drop, on my phone it will disconnect and then reconnect really quickly, is this to do with the dynamic IP? I don't know, but the issue is easily solved on my phone by configuring a static IP. My Windows PC on the other hand is a problem, I have to manually redo the manual IP settings every time I reconnect to the extender's network which is a total pain.
Does anyone have an idea what the issue could be? With the old router, the Xiaomi extender's connection was fine, with this new one (Cisco EPC3928S), I get the constant dropouts, maybe because the IP address is changing? The dropout issue does not occur when connected directly to the router.
The extender is my only option BTW, so I have to try and make it work, I have tried setting static IPs from the router itself but it doesn't work, the router doesn't see devices connected through the extender, setting a static IP for the extender from inside the router doesn't work either. Also worth noting that the extender shows up in the router device list as "STATIC IP ADDRESS" for whatever reason.
So dynamic IP is clearly the problem, any possible solutions inside the router? The extender itself is barely configurable.

Static IPs should not generally be a problem here. But which of your devices hand out the IPs on your network (the DHCP server)?

Do the main router and the extender have different SSIDs (network names)? What configuration does the extender offer?

all my devices generally have the exact same address for extended periods of time without setting anything to static. I am wondering why the device IP leases are changing so often.

if you set a specific wifi channel does it resolve?
